# How to mark as 'community wiki'?

Tags: discussion

I see an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/16412/47206) marked as 'community wiki'.

How to mark an answer as such?

Is it possible to mark a question as 'community wiki'?

Comment: Please check http://askubuntu.com/privileges/community-wiki and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts.

Comment: @jokerdino: is this a duplicate then? should i delete this?

Comment: @cipricus If this is a duplicate, it's not a duplicate of either of those. Not in the "can be closed as a duplicate of" sense. The first link is not a post at all, and the second link is a post on another site. I do not recommend you delete this. (Even if this were closed as a duplicate of another post here on Meta.AU, there would be no need for you to delete it--many duplicates [turn out to be helpful and are deliberately retained](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/).)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it has to be done by a moderator, unless it occurs naturally after 5 edits by 5 different people.

As jokerdino pointed out, you can get more information from the Stack Overflow meta [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) on the topic.

Comment: There's also a check box at the bottom of the answer.  Or at least there was.

Comment: @Seth lol yep, he was talking about questions specifically :)

Comment: *How to mark an answer as such?*  <-- Just sayin ;)

Comment: @Seth sorry lol - mind slip moment :P